# Erasing Last Input In A File

Tags: c++

How do I erase the last input in a text file ? Currently the text file contains the following:

5 
3
+
6

How do I remove the 6 ?

I don't have any code to show because I have no idea how to code it even after searching google for some time now. I was thinking an erase or trunc function but not too sure. Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file using a [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)
2. Read each word, a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), from the file.
3. Add the read words to a [`std::vector<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
4. Write the contents of all the elements of the vector save the last one. Write a space between each of the elements being written.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I hope you can continue to help !